# Widgets Opening In New Window - Unwanted

Tags: widgets

I am dumbfounded as to why my sidebar image widgets are opening links in a new window when I do not have the "open link in new window/tab" checked off. The box is blank.

My page is www.mountainobsession.com and the righthand sidebar has several images that when clicked, open in a new window. I do not want this.

Any insight would be appreciated - I am sure it a simple fix, but I just can't seem to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your image links have the target="_blank" attribute so that's why they open in a new window.

If you haven't checked the open in new window checkbox, you can always add a text widget and add those images manually like Text to make sure no 'target' attribute is being written.